# finding unions of line segments on a number line

Tags: algorithm

I have a number-line between 0 to 1000.  I have many line segments on the number line. All line segments' x1 is >= 0 and all x2 are < 1000.  All x1 and x2 are integers.

I need to find all of the unions of the line segments.

In this image, the line segments are in blue and the unions are in red:

[image]

Is there an existing algorithm for this type of problem?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "number-line of integers 0 to 1000". Are the coordinates of your segments integers between 0 and 1000 ?

Comment: @Yno: Yes, the x1 and x2 of the segments are between 0 and 1000. (updated the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use marzullo's algorithm (see Wikipedia for more details).
Here is a Python implementation I wrote:

```
def ip_ranges_grouping(range_lst):
    ##  Based on Marzullo's algorithm
    ##  Input: list of IP ranges
    ##  Returns a new merged list of IP ranges
    table = []
    for rng in range_lst:
        start,end = rng.split('-')
        table.append((ip2int(start),1))
        table.append((ip2int(end),-1))
    table.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
    for i in range(len(table) - 1):
        if((table[i][0] == table[i+1][0]) and ((table[i][1] == -1) and (table[i+1][1] == 1))):
           table[i],table[i+1] = table[i+1],table[i]

    merged = []
    end = count = 0
    while (end < len(table)):
        start = end
        count += table[end][1]
        while(count > 0): # upon last index, count == 0 and loop terminates
            end += 1
            count += table[end][1]
        merged.append(int2ip(table[start][0]) + '-' + int2ip(table[end][0]))
        end += 1
    return merged
```

Answer (score 1):

If the segments are not changed dynamically, it is a simple problem. Just sorting all the segments by the left end, then scanning the sorted elements:

```
struct Seg {int L,R;};

int cmp(Seg a, Seg b) {return a.L < b.L;}

int union_segs(int n, Seg *segs, Segs *output) {
  sort(segs, segs + n, cmp);
  int right_most = -1;
  int cnt = 0;
  for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
    if (segs[i].L > right_most) {
      right_most = segs[i].R;
      ++cnt;
      output[cnt].L = segs[i].L;
      output[cnt].R = segs[i].R;
    }
    if (segs[i].R > right_most) {
      right_most = segs[i].R;
      output[cnt].R = segs[i].R;
    }
  }
  return cnt+1;
}
```

The time complexity is O(nlogn) (sorting) + O(n) (scan).

If the segments are inserted and deleted dynamically, and you want to query the union at any time, you will need some more complicated data structures such as [range tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree).

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the coordinates of your segments are bounded ([0, 1000]) integers, you could use an array of size 1000 initialized with zeroes. You then run through your set of segments and set 1 on every cell of the array that the segment covers. You then only have to run through the array to check for contigous sequences of 1.

```
---      -----
  ---  ---
1111100111111100
```

The complexity depends on the number of segments but also on their length.

Here is another method, which also work for floating point segments. Sort the segments. You then only have to travel the sorted segments and compare the boundaries of each adjacent segments. If they cross, they are in the same union.