# Length of union of ranges

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I need to find length of union of ranges in  one dimension coordinate system. I have many ranges of form [a_i,b_i], and I need to find the length of union of these ranges. The ranges can be dynamically added or removed and can be queried at any state for length of union of ranges.

for example: is ranges are:

```
[0-4]
[3-6]
[8-10]
```

The output should be 8.

Is there any suitable data structure for the purpose with following upper bounds on complexity:

```
Insertion - O(log N)
Deletion - O(log N)
Query - O(log N)
```

Comment: no, there's no such structure that will do that, you'll have to write it yourself

Comment: @EugenHalca What do you mean, of course I will write it myself, I just queried for name.

Comment: What would make the output 8?  For the union, I see [0-6], [8-10].  If the possible values are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 8, 9, 10, the total is 10.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Not the possible values, the values that lie in between the range i.e. the length of the range for [0-6] it is 6 and [8-10] it is 2.

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja you could use bidimensional array like `int map[n][2] for java`, but if you want to make it easy and more readable and create object something like `Range(start,end)` and hold them in a `List<Range> also in java`

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja You know that the equation to calculate number of elements is `end - start + 1`, right?  Not just `end - start`?  By your calculation, there are 9 numbers in the range [1-10].  Are you choosing to exclude the 1 or the 10 from that range?  In the range [5-5], are there 0 or 1 elements?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein I do not need to find the number of elements, I need to find the length of that interval say for an interval [1-2] it must be 1, right? that's why I just used end-start.

Comment: @EugenHalca I need complexity of O(logN) in insertion, deletion and query.

Comment: all algorithms that i'd use are O(N), both using `bi-di array` or `oop style`

Comment: Are the endpoints always integers?

Comment: And is N the number of intervals, or the largest value? Edit: or is the largest value bounded in any way?

Comment: @AndyJones N is the number of intervals. The complexity discussed assume that the a operation on the length of any range is constant time i.e. a data type like int or long long int in C++.

Comment: Here you can find it's java implementation https://stackoverflow.com/a/63816110/12069124

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a moment, assume you have a sorted array, containing both start and end points, with the convention that a start point precedes an end point with the same coordinate. With your example, the array will contain

```
0:start, 3:start, 4:end, 6:end, 8:start, 10:end
```

(if there was an interval ending at 3, then `3:start` will precede `3:end`)

To do a query, perform a sweep from left to right, incrementing a counter on "start" and decrementing a counter on "end". You record as `S` the place where the counter increments from 0 and record as
`E` the place where the counter becomes zero. At this point you add to the total count the number of elements between `S` and `E`. This is also a point, where you can just replace the preceding intervals with the interval `[S, E]`.

Now, if you need O(log n) complexity for insertion/deletion, instead of in an array, you store the same elements (pairs of coordinate and start or end flag) in a balanced binary tree.
The sweep is then performed according to the inorder traversal.

The query itself stays O(n) complexity.

Comment: You can still use array and use binary search to insert/delete in O(log n).

Comment: And my guess is that for query the lower bound is Ω(n). Consider the case where there is a single interval covering the range of other intervals. When you delete that interval, you will need to check everything, I guess. But this is just an idea. =)

Comment: I guess the best I can get is O(n) for query. I tried some other data structure which stores the range as nodes(leaves) of tree, insertion and deletion were O(log N) but query in worst case is O(n).

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite `O(lg n)`, but would an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) or [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) suit your needs? You can keep the length of union in a variable, and when inserting or removing an interval, you can find in `O(lg n + m)` time what other *m* intervals intersect it, and then use that information to update the length variable in `O(m)` time.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a frequency array. Ex: If your range is (0,2) and (1,3), your frequency array should be [1, 2, 2, 1]. Also maintain a count of non-zero elements in the frequency array.

For insertion, increment the frequencies corresponding to that range. Update count when you increase from 0 to 1 (but not from 1 to 2 etc).

For deletion, decrement the frequencies. Similarly update count.

For query, output count.

Complexity is length of the range.