# How to join segments in Python?

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

This question concerns the union of segments.

I have an array (a) composed of 10* 4 elements (which are the extremities of lines: (x1,y1,x2,y2)). If I draw these 10 segments (see image), there are actually 2 lines only (cause some lines are on top of each others or have a small length).

```
a = np.array([[40,33,54,4],[40,34,54,5], [41,34,55,5], [43,34,57,7], [18,85,34,52], [15,83,30,51], [16,84,33,52], [42,34,56,5], [16,83,32,51]])
```

To process this, I was thinking of  taking the x1 and x2 positions of each line and then define segments. Similarly to what has been proposed, one could proceed as follows ([finding unions of line segments on a number line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241613/finding-unions-of-line-segments-on-a-number-line/12241707)).

For the first line (x1=40, x2=54), I could create a vector having 0 and 1 only, which would read:
00000.......0000001111....111100. 
That is 40 zeros, then 15 ones, and then 2 zeros. The length would be 57 as this is the largest x2 value.

I could proceeed like this for all lines.

Assuming three lines:

00011100000000

00000000001111

00111111000000

The result would be

**00111111001111**

And then I would know that there are two lines of length 6 (starting at 2) and 4 (starting at 10).

Is there an efficient to that in python ?

To create the array of 0 and 1 and I was doing :

```
import numpy as np

def array_zero_ones(x1, x2, xmax):
    # convert a segment into 0 and Ones
    arr = np.zeros(x1,dtype=np.bool)
    arr1 = np.ones((x2-x1+1),dtype=np.bool)
    arr2= np.zeros((xmax-x2),dtype=np.bool)
    arrall= np.concatenate([arr,arr1,arr2])
    return arrall


a = np.array([[3,33,6,4],[4,40,7,70], [9,98,11,111]])
max=np.max(a[:,2])

sum_array_all = np.zeros(max+1,dtype=np.bool)

for i in range(len(a)):
        sum_array_all =  sum_array_all + array_zero_ones(a[i,0],a[i,2],max)

print(sum_array_all)

#still need to find all non 1 values in this array
```

Not sure it is efficient....
Best,

W

[image]

Comment: Is it clear how many lines will there be per picture (is it always 2)? can they cross over? do they have the same or similar length each time? If they have a similar shape, you could maybe do just a convolution of the image with a prototypical image and look where the maximums are. convolutions should be quick and easy.

Comment: The lines can be of any length, have any direction and can cross. That is why, I cannot use a cross-correlation algorithm. Here this is just a sub image where two filaments have exactly the same direction.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `RANSAC` to estimate straight line and get it from there. `RANSAC` is very simple and robust method, though non-deterministic. Unless your images are prone to noise, it should work fine for your case. There's example [here](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_ransac.html).
There's also great visual and intuitive explanationon [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus).

Comment: Thanks but I already have checked some image processing methods and the hough transform works best in my case. The only issue is the one I am posting here.

Comment: Hough lines can still give you some false positives and you have to postprocess its results.

Comment: Take min and max coordinates of your lines. Draw a single line using those coordinates. Do you need that line to visually resemble original data?

Comment: I am still very happy with the hough lines algorithm. My problem has more to do with the union of segments.

Comment: @2WFR.... what do you expect from a solution?  I am hearing "Hough lines are insufficient, but I don't want to use anything but Hough lines"

Comment: I never have told Hough lines are not suffiicient. They just need to be processed. I should not have mentioned I was doing Image processing cause it is a general qurestion.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. 
Not sure it is very efficient but it works.

```
def return_segments_along_x_axis(arr):
    # array should be as [[13,33,14,4],[3,33,6,4],[4,40,7,70], [9,98,11,111],[14,98,16,111]]
    # I calculate the max of x2 for all those lines
    max=np.max(arr[:,2])
    # Array init
    sum_array_all = np.zeros(max+1,dtype=np.bool)
    # For the projection along the x axis, I assign TRUE if there is a segment at a given pixel
    # And then sum over all lines.
    # If I have those lines (along the x axis)
    #    ---    
    #      ----    
    #             ---
    # Then the value would be
    #    ------   ---
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        sum_array_all =  sum_array_all + array_zero_ones(a[i,0],a[i,2],max)
    # I then find the indexes of the True Values 
    array_ind_TRUE_index = np.where(np.r_[False, sum_array_all[1:] > sum_array_all[:-1]])[0]
    # Now I retrieve the length of the segment 
    # Init arrays
    arr_Length_TRUE = np.empty(shape=[0, 1])
    arr_lines_along_given_axis = np.empty(shape=[0, 2])
    # Loop
    for i in range(len(array_ind_TRUE_index)):
        temp_array_1 =sum_array_all[array_ind_TRUE_index[i]:]
        val_temp = (temp_array_1 !=True).argmax(axis=0)
        if val_temp == 0:
            val_temp = len(temp_array_1)
        arr_Length_TRUE =   np.append(arr_Length_TRUE,val_temp)
    #For a given direction, this gives (along the x axis), the x1 values and lengths of the segments
    arr_lines_along_given_axis = [[array_ind_TRUE_index[i], arr_Length_TRUE [i]] for i, i in zip(range(0,len(array_ind_TRUE_index)), range(0,len(array_ind_TRUE_index)))]
    return(arr_lines_along_given_axis)
```